# how to encrypt a text present in a string in unix using gpg

Tags: java, unix, encryption, gnupg

I have to encrypt a content inside a string buffer.

Currently Im encrypting the file. I write string buffer into a file and then encrypt using following command.

```
gpg --recipient "raj" --output "C:\a.txt.gpg" --yes --encrypt "C:\a.txt"
```

But due to security reason, we dont need to write into a file and the content should be passed directly to the gpg command.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, using a pipe?

```
echo hello | gpg --recipient "owlstead" --output deleteme.gpg --yes --encrypt
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer. I have this format to encrypt and it is present in string buffer:

String buffer has this content

This book is red
This book is yellow
This book is black

When I pass this to the gpg

echo $stringBuffer | gpg --recipient "owlstead" --output deleteme.gpg --yes --encrypt


I dnt get the desired result

Comment: The content is in different line

Comment: Try `"${stringBuffer}"` instead.